# how to set default code format or code style in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

Currently my eclipse follows this code format:

```
public class TempClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

So when I select all code and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +   <kbd>Shift</kbd>    +  <kbd>F</kbd> ,
it formatts the code in above style.

Is there any way I can set my default code format to this:

```
public class TempClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to read [**Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: Yes, it is in the project settings, but then you get to say whether it is project by project or global.

Comment: @downvoter , please leave a reason to downvote

Comment: @PaulVargas : please mention if I missed any specific convention point

Comment: yup! See the section in _6.4 Class and Interface Declarations_ in the  [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: @PaulVargas : yep , read it , if you are pointing out the braces position selection by me , then i would stick to my style , this is the convention i choose to neglect for my own self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this:

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> [Edit...] -> Braces

There you can configure it!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project->java -> code Style->Formatter->Configure Workspace Settings..(link on top right)>Select Active Profile->Edit->Braces(Tab)

Look for Brace Position:

You can change the brace position, for eg) constructor declaration to next line

You can create a new profile as well if you want(instead of using the Eclipse Built-in]

[image]

Change the sample code.

and Apply changes.

Version:Helios Service Release 2